# ResourceManager.GetString returns null

Tags: c#, sql, embedded-resource

I am trying to read some .sql files that I have embedded in a resx file called SQLUpdateScripts. All my files in SQLupdateScripts.resx are in format 00001.sql,00002.sql,0003.sql etc.
I want to read the content of each sql file and execute it based on two variables

```
for (int i = DbVersion+1; i <= FileDbVersion; i++)
            {
                 string updateScripts = "script_" + i.ToString("D5");
....
var sqlqueries = myString.Split(new[] { "\nGO", "\ngo" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
etc....
```

I tried many suggestions in stackoverflow but all of them are returning null or exception

```
ResourceManager sqLUpdateScripts = new ResourceManager(typeof(SQLUpdateScripts));
                string myString = sqLUpdateScripts.GetString(updateScripts);
```

also

```
object[] args = new object[] { updateScripts };

SQLUpdateScripts obj = new SQLUpdateScripts();
obj.GetType().InvokeMember(updateScripts,
BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
Type.DefaultBinder, obj, args);
```

The code in SqlUpdateScripts.Designer.cs for every sql file is

```
internal static string script_00001 
    {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("script_00001", resourceCulture);
            }
    }
internal static string script_00002 
   {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("script_00002", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

I read that I must use reflection to call each file as method by using the invokeMember gives me Exception that cannot find class SqlUpdateScripts.script_0001'. 
When I tried using the ResourceManager it just return myString as null.

If I called by hand:

```
var sqlqueries = SQLUpdateScript.script_0001.Split(new[] { "\nGO", "\ngo" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

it works fine but I want to use variables for the filename and not a standard filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
It was a dump error I made. I gave wrong values while testing in DBVersion and fileDBVersion so when I used

```
for (int i = DbVersion+1; i <= FileDbVersion; i++)
```

instead of giving me value script_00001 it gave me the value script_01001
So now that it is working I found that you can call files as strings in resx files with two ways

First:

```
ResourceManager sqLUpdateScripts = new ResourceManager(typeof(SQLUpdateScripts));
string myString = sqLUpdateScripts.GetString(updateScripts);
```

Second way:

```
string resVal = SQLUpdateScripts.ResourceManager.GetString(updateScripts, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

GetString in second way has two overloads, one is with out CultureInfo and one is with specify the CultureInfo in case you want to call another language for example.

I don't know if there is a way to avoid future mistakes while calling wrong resx resource , maybe if there is a way to enumerate all the resources and then just choose one.

If I find a way I will add it here.